# How do you prove that $\ln|f(z)|$ is harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic and nonzero in a domain $D$.  Prove that $\ln|f(z)|$ is harmonic in $D$.

I know the laplacian equation but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: $f$ is analytic, so it satisfies Cauchy-Riemann. Try to show Cauchy-Riemann for $f$ implies Laplacian for $\log|f|$.

Comment: You may find this useful: $\ln|f|=\frac{1}{2}\ln|f|^2= \frac{1}{2}(\ln f+\ln \bar f)$.

Comment: @5pm If you separate the log, you can't guarantee that $f$ and $\bar{f}$ stay in its domain.

Comment: @julien Harmonicity is a local property.

Comment: @5pm I am aware of that. But I assume we work with the principal branch of log. Then what do you do if $f(z)=-1$?

Comment: @julien Then I stop assuming that we work with the principal branch of $\log$. :) As long as $f(z_0)\ne 0$, $\log f$ makes sense in a neighborhood of $z_0$ (we can choose any branch we wish, constants don't matter for harmonicity).

Comment: @5pm Let's stick to the principal branch for a second;) If $f(z)=-1$, you change for another determination of the log? I see. Ok, modulo this justification, using your formula makes computations slightly easier than in my proof. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 18):

**EDIT:** As **5pm** points out below, this is of course actually good enough since every domain in $\mathbb{C}$ is locally simply connected and harmonicity is a local property!

This was too long for a comment, but I thought it might be nice to know.

There is a much nicer, less computational way to prove this result if we assume further that $D$ is simply connected. In particular, recall that if $D$ is a simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$ and $h$ a non-vanishing holomorphic function on $D$ then $h=e^g$ for some holomorphic function $g$ (this is because we can define a branch of the logarithm on $D$).

So, if $D$ was simply connected we'd know that $f=e^g$ for some holomorphic $g$, and then

$$\log|f|=\log|e^g|=\log(\exp(\text{Re}(g))=\text{Re}(g)$$

and since $g$ is harmonic (since $g$ was holomorphic!) we're done.

Comment: And the assumption of $D$ being simply-connected is not needed. Every point of $D$ is contained in a disk (which *is* simply connected), and harmonicity is a local property.

Comment: @5pm Absolutely! Good call.

Answer (score 13):

Note: here is how you can prove this at the very beginning of a complex analysis course. Once you know how to define branches of log, Alex's approach is recommended.

Recall that analyticity is characterized by the Cauchy Riemann equation
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0=\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial z}
$$
and that the Laplacian satisfies
$$
\Delta=4\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial \bar{z}}.
$$

Now differentiate
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\log (f\bar{f})=\frac{1}{f\bar{f}}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} \bar{f}+f \frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial \bar{z}} \right)=\frac{1}{\bar{f}}\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial \bar{z}}
$$
and differentiate once more
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial \bar{z}}\log(f\bar{f})=\frac{-\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial z}}{\bar{f}^2}\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial \bar{z}}+\frac{1}{\bar{f}}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial \bar{z}}\bar{f}=\frac{1}{\bar{f}}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \bar{z}\partial z}\bar{f}=0.
$$

So $$\log |f|=\frac{1}{2}\log |f|^2=\frac{1}{2}\log (f\bar{f})$$
is harmonic.

Note: all the cancellations are due to the Cauchy-Riemann equation.